# Are these phrases downward entailing?

Tags: semantics, theoretical-linguistics, formal-semantics, entailment

Please consider the following phrases with respect to downward entailment:

Mary remembers that French students saw her.
Mary remembers that tall French students saw her. 
(in my opinion, this is not downward entailing)

Mary remembers that Italian food is good.
Mary remembers that Pizza is good. 
(Rather downward entailing)

Mary remembers that her parents had Italian food.
Mary remembers that her mother had Italian food.
(Definitely downward entailing)

Why does it seem that some phrases are downward entailing but the others don't? Is it maybe a problem of sets? "Mother" is rather an indispensable part of parents whereas French students are still French students even without tall ones -> subset. But what about pizzas?

Comment: "Downward entailing" means nothing until one specifies the proposition that is supposedly entailed, and the construction or lexical choice that supposedly licenses the entailment.

Comment: I understand, but if we look at the definition of downward entailment "if E ⊂ F, then ‘Det Fs are G’ entails ‘Det Es are G" we can normally make very good assumptions about if a subset pf a set is included or not in a statement. So why allow some subset inclusions and others don't?

Comment: Using a logical definition for a pragmatic relation always leaves holes in the coverage; logic comes after understanding, not before.